# Should "this" be always used as the Context in creating a new object?

Tags: java, android

When a new object is made, it often goes:

```
TextView textView = new TextView(this)
```

Here, should we always use "this" pointer (an instance of an Activity, normally) as the Context of TextView? For me it seems that any Context would work in many circumstances, such as the following method.

```
  TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(textSize);
        textView.setTextColor(textColor);
        textView.setText(text);
        tableRow.addView(textView);
```

And my assertion is, as I am not adopting any resources, any Context could replace "this." (I assume it is wrong.) Why should we use "this" instead of any other Contexts?

Comment: Please add the correct language tag (I presume it would be Java), and name the library you are using (the one providing the `TextView` class), ideally also in the form of a tag. This helps you to get the right people looking at your question.

Comment: It depends on the context (sic). Helpful reading: http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/

Answer (score 2):

> Here, should we always use "this" pointer (an instance of an Activity, normally) as the Context of TextView?

Occasionally, there is a better choice, but that's usually in obvious circumstances:

- You are using `Presentation` to route stuff to an external display, and so you use the `Context` associated with that `Display`
- You are writing an `InputMethodService` and need to return the `View` in `onCreateInputView()`
- You are writing a `DreamService` and need to call `setContentView()` and choose to create your widgets in Java code rather than use a layout
- Etc.

> I am not adopting any resources

Your *code* is not. Your *app* is, in the form of framework classes accessing style/theme resources for your activity (or app).

The [blog post by Dave Smith](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/06/context/) in laalto's comment is an excellent starting point for choosing the right `Context` for the right situation.